# How Spark compares data of type Boolean and String

Tags: sql, apache-spark, casting

SQL:

```sql
SELECT 'true' = true;
```

I know the result is true, but I want to know how Spark compares the two:

- cast true as 'true' and then just compare two string type;
- cast 'true' as true and then compare two boolean type.

Which way does Spark use?

The same happens when comparing date and string or timestamp and string:

```sql
SELECT '2022-01-02' > date('2022-01-03');
SELECT '2022-08-12 01:00:00.123456' < timestamp('2019-08-12 01:00:00.123456');
```

I'm a novice at Spark. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to learn is to ask Spark to explain the plan.

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT 'true' = true").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [true AS (CAST(true AS BOOLEAN) = true)#53]
+- *(1) Scan OneRowRelation[]

scala> spark.sql("SELECT '2022-01-02' > date('2022-01-03')").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [false AS (CAST(2022-01-02 AS DATE) > CAST(2022-01-03 AS DATE))#55]
+- *(1) Scan OneRowRelation[]

scala> spark.sql("SELECT '2022-08-12 01:00:00.123456' < timestamp('2019-08-12 01:00:00.123456')").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [false AS (CAST(2022-08-12 01:00:00.123456 AS TIMESTAMP) < CAST(2019-08-12 01:00:00.123456 AS TIMESTAMP))#57]
+- *(1) Scan OneRowRelation[]
```

We can clearly see that in all cases Spark attempts to cast string to the other type (boolean, date, timestamp, int, ...).